# How can you turn off messages in mongolite R package

Tags: r, mongolite

Is there anyway to turn off the Mongo Messages sent out by the mongolite R package? I've tried setting verbose = FALSE in the mongo() function, but that doesn't make any difference to these messages. The source code refers to a log_level but I can't see any option to set that anywhere.

This happens whenever I'm connecting to a replicaSet, using any username (but this example is for user 'moso')

> Mongo Message: SCRAM: "moso" authenticated
>   Mongo Message: SCRAM: authenticating "moso" (step 1)
>   Mongo Message: SCRAM: authenticating "moso" (step 2)
>   Mongo Message: SCRAM: authenticating "moso" (step 3)

The messages are repeated lots of times in my logs, and making it hard to see actual errors.

Comment: Currently this is not possible I think, but we could add a feature like that. Can you open an issue on github?

Comment: https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/blob/2bca2663e7e743e4f9591abe99228bf6a2ef6c27/src/onload.c#L15 is the culprit @jeroen … issue filed: https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/issues/31

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 1.0 of `mongolite` introduces a new function `mongo_options` which you can use to override the global log level.

The manual page has some more information. Log level 3 should hide the connect messages. You can go even lower to suppress warnings and errors as well but I would not recommend that.

```
mongo_options(log_level = 3)
con <- mongo("mtcars", url = "mongodb://readwrite:test@ds043942.mongolab.com:43942/jeroen_test")
```

Update: this is on CRAN now.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent R package. Any idea when this change will be available on the CRAN?

Comment: I think the next release of mongolite will be when version 1.4.0 of the mongo c driver is released. For now you can just use the github version.

Comment: @Jeroen, c driver version 1.4 was released some days ago. See [that link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases). Tks for the amazing work with `mongolite`, it's a extremely useful package.